# Text formatting bug - code in middle of ordered list items

Tags: support, formatting

Noticed a bug when edited a question. If You have a list with multi-level items, inserting code in the middle of them, breaks level indentions for further list items after the code.

See example below - indention for list item `1.3.` is broken (displayed as a first level item, not second) and it resets indentions for further list items, based on `1.3.` item.

1. first, open this

   1.1. then click that

   1.2. execute code below

```
sample code
lorem
ipsum
```

1.3. check if everyting is OK <<--- **indention displayed as first level item**

2. then switch to this

   2.1. move this from here to there

   2.2. all done

Is there a way to format question with correct indentions after the code is placed in the middle of list items? Or this formatting is not allowed/recommended - insert code in the middle of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add code block in the list while properly formatting it. You need to add enough spaces (6 or more) for the code block to have the same level as the list item's indent.

---

1. first, open this

   1.1. then click that

   1.2. execute code below

   ```
   sample code
   lorem
   ipsum
   ```

   1.3. check if everyting is OK <<--- **indention correctly displayed as second level item**
2. then switch to this

   2.1. move this from here to there

   2.2. all done

---

Markdown (with trailing dots for clarity, replace with whitespace instead)

```
1. first, open this

.1.1. then click that

.1.2. execute code below

........sample code
........lorem
........ipsum

.1.3. check if everyting is OK <<--- **indention correctly displayed as second level item**

2. then switch to this

.2.1. move this from here to there

.2.2. all done
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank You! :)